# How to find a random user with relations in laravel eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I have the following query where I am generating a random user.

```
    User::inRandomOrder()
        ->where('role', 'lender')
        ->whereNotIn('id', $this->lender_ids)
        ->where('verified', 'verified')
        ->first();
```

Now, I want to add another where condition to check if the user has at least one transaction. The problem here is that transactions are in another table and I do have a one-to-many relation with users and transactions where each user can have multiple transactions but a transaction can belong to only one user.

Now, I want to add a where condition to ensure that this random user must have at least one transaction.  So how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `has` will solve your problem, it checks the existence of relationship, try this:

```
    User::inRandomOrder()
        ->where('role', 'lender')
        ->whereNotIn('id', $this->lender_ids)
        ->where('verified', 'verified')
        ->has('transactions')
        ->first();
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although I had to call it as a static method like User::has('transactions')